# Returning Html/Php code from a database

Tags: php, html, database

I'm trying to make a 'log' for a litte project.

The info what has to be in the log is in a other table in the database, I would like to get the html form from the database with the variable info in it which it takes from the other table.

Code which is in the Database:

```
<div class="container">
<ul class="timeline">
    <li>
        <div class="timeline-panel">
            <div class="timeline-heading">
                <h4 class="timeline-title"><?php echo $player->name ?></h4>
                <p class="text-muted"><?php echo $player->time ?></p>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-body">
                <p>While slaying <?php echo $player->npcName ?> I found an <?php echo $player->drop ?>!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Class with functions:

```
class player
{
    public $name;
    public $time;
    public $npcName;
    public $drop;
    public $level;

    public $code;


    function getPlayer(){
        $db = new dbCon();
        $sql = 'SELECT * from player where id = 1';
        foreach($db->getCon()->query($sql) as $row ){
            $this->name = $row['name'];
            $this->time = $row['time'];
            $this->npcName = $row['npcName'];
            $this->drop = $row['drop'];
            $this->level = $row['level'];
            $db = null;
        }
    }

    function getLogForm(){
        $db = new dbCon();
        $sql = 'SELECT * from htmltemplate WHERE id = 1';

        foreach($db->getCon()->query($sql) as $row){
            $this->code = $row['code'];
        }    
    }      
}
```

Echo in index.php

```
<?php echo $player->code ?>
```

[form code in database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbTQl.png)

[Current output](http://prntscr.com/92kw5y)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `$row['code']` is a string, it won't be parsed and variables won't be replaced. For such cases use either `sprintf` or `str_replace` functions.

For example, you can store your html-template as:

```
<div class="timeline-panel">
    <div class="timeline-heading">
        <h4 class="timeline-title">#PLAYER_NAME#</h4>
        <p class="text-muted">#PLAYER_TIME#</p>
```

And then output like:

```
<?php echo str_replace(
    array('#PLAYER_NAME#', '#PLAYER_TIME#'), 
    array($player->name, $player->time), 
    $player->code
);?>
```

And of course you should have `$player` object available.